# C# Unit test DbContext.Database method Error- No database provider has been configured for this DbContext

Tags: c#, unit-testing, entity-framework-core, moq, extension-methods

I am writing unit tests in C# using Moq framework. I am encountering the error `No database provider has been configured for this DbContext` while writing and debugging test case for a method that internally calls the following:

`DbContext.Database.ExecuteSql`

I tried the following, where context is the mocked DbContext, but the error persists.

`var mockDatabaseFacade = new Mock<DatabaseFacade>(context.Object); context.Setup(x => x.Database).Returns(mockDatabaseFacade.Object);`

Comment: I would argue that there is literally no point in mocking database context.

Comment: @GuruStron Is there any other way to resolve this error when it encounters these methods?

Comment: I would use either in-memory SQLite or test containers